# are there msproject abilities in tfs or connection to MSproject and Clarizen?

Tags: tfs

My company is developing a multi discipline product.
For the software project management we use tfs and scrum method.
I wish that all others disciplines (electronics, mechanics...) will also use tfs for task and defect management.
In order to do so we need more abilities such as resource management (e.g. machine prototype, hardware simulator...) to find over capacity of resources, connect tasks to milestones and more.
Are there any utilities, add-on's or whatever that can help us with these needs.

OK, i got the MSProject connection solution from Jim.
does anyone know about such a connection with Clarizen
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use them (TFS & MS Project) together?

Please see [tutorial](http://tutorial.visualstudioteamsystem.com/details.aspx?item=58).